# CombineReducers with multiple subreducers vs. reducers that set key-values on the same object/map

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I can compose state as follows with `combineReducers` with a reducer function handling each part of the state (`foo` and `bar`):

```
function foo(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.A:
      return action.value;
    default:
      state;
  }
}

function bar(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.B:
      return action.value;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

combineReducers({ foo, bar });
```

Or have case reducer functions that correspond to actions, which take the whole state and set just one key-value on them. (Could be using immutable.js as below or just plain ojects)

```
function a(state, value) {
  state.set('foo', action.value);
}

function b(state, value) {
  state.set('bar', action.value);
}

function reducer(state = Map()) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.A:
      return a(state, action.value);
    case types.B:
      return b(state, action.value);
  }
}
```

Are there certain advantages of one style over the other?